# More efficient way to get node Index on the page?

Tags: jquery, click, position

I need to store the dom index of each element on the page.  The elements may or may not have either an id or class name to identify them in the dom. I have a method that works but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to code this?

Thanks for any assistance...

Code:

```
$('textarea,input,select,img,a,span,label,embed,object,caption,map,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,ul,th,p,td,div').click(function (event) {

            if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "textarea") {
                var nodeIndex = $("textarea").index(this);
                var nodeName = $(this).get(0).nodeName
                alert(nodeName + "," + nodeIndex);
            }

            if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
                var nodeIndex = $("input").index(this);
                var nodeName = $(this).get(0).nodeName
                alert(nodeName + "," + nodeIndex);
            }

            if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "img") {
                var nodeIndex = $("img").index(this);
                var nodeName = $(this).get(0).nodeName
                alert(nodeName + "," + nodeIndex);
            }

            //and so on...
         });
```

Comment: your code returns 0 index for all elements http://jsfiddle.net/ANAZ9/

 What exactly are you trying to do here? I've textarea, input and H1 on the page, If I click on textarea, should i get the index 0, for input its 1 and so on?

Comment: @codef0rmer Yes if I have 3 inputs and I click on the second one it returns 1, or if I had 4 images on the page and you click on the 4th the index is 3.

Comment: @codef0rmer - duplicate some of the tags in your demo, will see answer yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that might help

```
var noSearch=['script', 'style'];

$('body *').not( noSearch.join()).click(function(){
    var nodeName=this.nodeName
    var idx=$(nodeName).index(this);

    alert( nodeName +'  '+idx)
})
```

EDIT: I took approach you may have less tags to exclude than include

Comment: that almost works.  When I click on an element, it also picks up ever element underneath the clicked node.  So if there are a bunch of divs under an image I get an alert for each.  I tried e.stopImmediatePropagation(); but I need to let the dom event occur after the click.

Comment: put a demo together on fiddle.net with a better outline of what objective is, alert is obviously not what you need for storing

Comment: I added : if (event.target === this) { alert( nodeName +'  '+idx) } and then it works perfectly!  Thanks for steering me in a new direction :)